# How to read data from MySQL via Spark WORKER nodes?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. We have the legacy java spark code that reads data from mysql. However, it loads the data at the "master" node and then broad cast to the workers based on the divided groups. The code is shown as below:

```
    Map<Integer, ObjectModel> allGroupInputModels = loadAllDataByGroups();
    Broadcast<Map<Integer, ObjectModel>> partialObjectModel = sc.broadcast(allGroupInputObjectModels);
    
    eventDF = sparkHelper.getEventPresenterDataFrame(groupIds, minDate, maxDate);
    eventProductDF = sparkHelper.getEventProductDataFrame(groupIds, minDate, maxDate);
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<Event>> eventsPairRDD = sparkHelper.getCombinedEventRDD(eventDF, eventProductDF).repartition(numPartition);
    
    Map<Integer, ObjectModel> allGroupInputModels = loadAllDataByGroups();
    Broadcast<Map<Integer, ObjectModel>> partialModel = sc.broadcast(allGroupInputObjectModels);
    
    eventDF = sparkHelper.getEventPresenterDataFrame(groupIds, minDate, maxDate);
    eventProductDF = sparkHelper.getEventProductDataFrame(groupIds, minDate, maxDate);
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<Event>> eventsPairRDD = sparkHelper.getCombinedEventRDD(eventDF, eventProductDF).repartition(numPartition);
        
    JavaRDD<ResultObject> resultJavaRDD = eventsPairRDD.map(r -> {
   
                        Integer groupId = r._1;
                        System.out.println("Processing Group: " + groupId);
        
                        List<Event> groupEvents = r._2;
        
                        Map<Integer, ObjectModel> allGroupModel = partialModel.getValue();
        
                        ObjectModel groupModel = allGroupModel.get(groupId);
                
                        groupModel.setEvents(groupEvents);
        
                        // process to get the results using the groupModel
                        .....
        
                        return result;
                    });
```

Note that we load the data for all groups out side of the map function, which I believe that means all the data loading was done at the master node, and the broadcast to the worker node for calculation.
Am I understanding this correctly? If yes, then I worried that the data will be too big so the master memory will not be enough. Any way we can move this data loading step into the worker node? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: wow... this is a bit of sicko code when you compare to Spark those days. I am not even sure it was supposed to work like that. Have a look at https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch08 on how a MySQL ingestion can be done. You'll see that it is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there are much things to salvage from the code. A traditional JDBC ingestion looks like that:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName(
        "MySQL to Dataframe using a JDBC Connection")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate();

// Using properties
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "root");
props.put("password", "Spark<3Java");
props.put("useSSL", "false");

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().jdbc(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?serverTimezone=EST",
    "actor", props);
df = df.orderBy(df.col("last_name"));

// Displays the dataframe and some of its metadata
df.show(5);
df.printSchema();
System.out.println("The dataframe contains " + df
    .count() + " record(s).");
```

Once you have ingested the data in the dataframe (`Dataset<Row>`) you can perform all your operations. Nothing is done by the driver here. No need for broadcast.

The `pox.xml` associated to it contains:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <scala.version>2.12</scala.version>
  <spark.version>3.0.0</spark.version>
  <mysql.version>8.0.16</mysql.version>
  ...
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <!-- Spark -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
   <version>${spark.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
   <version>${spark.version}</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>${mysql.version}</version>
  </dependency>
...
```